# Convert sql to excel formula

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup

I have 2 tables in excel.
Table 1

```
Item Quantity_Required    Quantity_Remaining
A     5
B     10
C     3
```

Table 2

```
Source Item Quantity
1        A    2 
2        A     1 
1        B     5
```

My result should be to fill in Quantity_Remaining column in Table 1

```
Table 1 
Item Quantity_Required    Quantity_Remaining
A     5                         2
B     10                        5
C     3                         3
```

The logic in SQL code is as follows.

```
SELECT A.Item,
A.Quantity_Required,
A.Quantity_Required - B.Quantity as Quantity_Remaining
FROM Table1 A
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT Item,
SUM(Quantity)
FROM Table2
GROUP BY Item) B
ON A.Item = B.Item
```

I need pointers on how to translate this to Excel.

Comment: Use SUMIF to get the total used to subtract from the amount.

Answer (score 0):

For data placed in excel sheet like below, you can use this formula:

```
=$B2-SUMPRODUCT(($A2=$B$8:$B$10)*($C$8:$C$10))
```

So the second part of formula `SUMPRODUCT` is looking for cells in range `B8:B10` which match with `A2` and then taking their values from column `C` and adding them.

[image]